# IEnumerable -- how non-empty collection can be empty at the same time?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I cannot figure this out. The workflow of passing IEnumerable<T> (T is some my class, but it is not relevant here) basically looks like this:

```
var a = GetEntireCollection(); // so I get IEnumerable<T>
...
var b = a.Where(condition1);
...
var c = b.Where(condition2);
...
```

So I filter out more and more items from the collection, finally I call:

```
if (z.IsEmpty())
    throw new Exception();
Foo(z);
```

and Foo is

```
public void Foo(IEnumerable<T> p)
{
    pool = p.OrderByDescending(it => it.MyProperty).ToList();

    if (pool.IsEmpty())
        throw new Exception(pool.Count().ToString() + ", " + p.Count().ToString());
    ...
```

All I do, is order the collection.

Now, my program crashes with exception -- it says that p has Count = 1, and pool has Count = 0. What's more when I point out p and require the results (I run program using Visual Studio) it says, the collection yielded with no results (or somethig similar, not verbatim quote).

Questions:

1. how can non-empty collection become empty just by reordering?
2. how can collection Count can be > 0, when there are no items in it?

I am asking because I would like to know how to avoid this situation, but honestly, when I am looking at the code it seems 100% legit for me.

**Technical background**:

- it is pure C# code, no asm inlines, or anything like this
- no threads
- no external libraries, except for Where (which comes from Linq) this is all my code

### Edits

**Edit 1**

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll)
{
    var iter = coll.GetEnumerator();
    return !iter.MoveNext();
}
```

**Edit 2**

Just before I call Foo(z) I check if the z is empty, so the code looks like this:

```
if (z.IsEmpty())
    throw new Exception();
Foo(z);
```

## SOLVED

As Jon suggested (C# sharpshooting I would say) one of the conditions was time dependent. So when the collection evaluation was forced the condition changed and I get in fact another collection.

Comment: do you have threads in your program?

Comment: I just wanted to add this piece :-) -- no.

Comment: That `IsEmpty()` is a bit iffy to me: no disposal of the `IEnumerator<T>`, plus it's basically just duplicating `!Any()`.

Comment: What do you mean by disposal? Yes, it does, now I realize I should put there (inside) call to Any. I prefer IsEmpty (name) because it reads better in longer code.

Comment: @macias: Calling `!Any()` would work, or you could just wrap your code in a `using` block. A lot of developers don't realize that `IEnumerator<T>` inherits from `IDisposable`, to account for enumerators that may acquire resources or otherwise require some sort of disposal. So in any generic code like this you should always dispose of the enumerator just to be safe.

Comment: @Dan you for the tip, could you explain or paste a link, why I should dispose enumerator manually? I understand it for a clash scenario, but this not one of them.

Comment: @macias: In most cases it ends up not being a big deal. I'm just pointing out that your `IsEmpty` method accepts *any* `IEnumerable<T>` implementation, so it should dispose of the object passed to it, as the contract of `IEnumerable<T>` dictates. It's not really about clashes, necessarily. You could have a type that connects to a data feed over a network connection, for example. Just a bit of general advice -- not the most important thing in the world.

Comment: @macias: Sorry, by "the object passed to it," I meant to say, "the enumerator provided by the object passed to it" (i.e., whatever's returned by `GetEnumerator`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that evaluating the conditions twice is effectively changing the results.

Each time you iterate through `p`, it will re-evaluate the data, including the `Where` clauses. So you're doing that once to populate `pool`, and then again to print out `p.Count()`.

Without any more information about what `GetEntireCollection` does or what the `Where` conditions are, it's hard to say what's going on... but that's one possible explanation. If you can post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, that would help a lot.

Comment: Thank you, it could be a cause, when looking I don't see any time dependant conditions, but of course I can miss something. I will try to track it (or simplify the code) and will post update ASAP.

Comment: I found out I already added check for being empty before I call Foo. Even with deferred exection should this condition hold true (once executed) in all subsequent calls?

Comment: @macias: Nope - because unless `z` is something concrete and non-deferred (like a `List<T>`) its results can change every time you iterate over it. Note that it doesn't have to be time-dependent... if any of your conditions have side effects, that could cause the same kind of problem.

Comment: Found it :-( Sad face because it is embarrasing for me, however on the other side it was very valuable lesson for me -- despite I know about late execution I was bite so easily ;-). Many thanks (I cannot upvote +10 for the help though :-D)!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's empty because of **Deferred Execution**, most query operators execute not when
constructed, but when enumerated (in other words, when MoveNext is called on its
enumerator).

So if you change it to  :

```
var c = b.Where(condition2).ToList();
```

And then call Foo(c) it will work.

Comment: I don't think so -- the `Count` call should cause `p` to be evaluated.

Comment: While this *may* end up being explained by repeated evaluation (which is in turn due to deferred execution) you haven't really explained why `p.Count()` would be 1 but `pool.Count()` would be 0. We don't really have enough information at the moment.

Comment: @Dan: Count call is made in the Exception, before that I don't see any count call.

Comment: @ace: So that forces it to be evaluated once, and prior to that it will be evaluated due to the `OrderByDescending(...).ToList()` call.

Comment: @ace: But the exception is thrown on `pool.IsEmpty()`, which shouldn't be subject to deferred execution since `pool` is a `List<T>`. It seems the main question is: why would `pool.Count()` and `p.Count()` return disparate values? Personally I don't think deferred execution can answer this.

Comment: @Dan: It can, if the conditions effectively change between executions. For example, consider `x.Where(x => DateTime.Now.Seconds > 30)` - that clearly has the ability to return different results each time it's executed. So `pool` could end up with 0 items, but when evaluating `p.Count()` you could end up with 1. However, we need more information before we know if that's actually the problem.

Comment: @Jon: True, my statement was too broad. What I meant was that I don't think ace's explanation is accurate; he seems to be saying that `Count()` is bound to return 0 because the enumeration doesn't happen (which is false). At least that's how I interpreted this answer. But yeah, the ramifications of deferred execution could ultimately be to blame in a different sense, I concede.

Comment: @Dan: Agreed on all counts - I suspect ace is a bit confused about what deferred execution really entails, but I also expect deferred execution to be *something* to do with it :)

Comment: Just a comment -- converting it to something solid like ToList would of course solve the problem, but I was interested why it happens (about the source of the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you show will call `GetEntireCollection` multiple times.

So maybe this method is returning different results on successive invocations.

Comment: No, it's not going to call `GetEntireCollection` multiple times. The source code within `GetEntireCollection` will execute multiple times *if* it's an iterator block, but the method itself will only be called once.